# Unable to connect to second generation from SDK on OS X

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I am unable to connect to a second generation Cloud SQL database from my OS/X SDK environment using PHP. I get a 1045 "Access denied for user 'user'@'ip address' (using password: YES)" error. I am using SSL for the direct IP connections.

My setup works fine for first generation Cloud SQL databases and it also works from MySQL Workbench.

[image]

I am migrating from a first to a second generation database and running tests. The only thing that changes is IP address and the referenced SSL files. From the PHP program the connection string looks like this for both generation 1 and generation 2 connections when using the SDK:

```
mysql:host=<IP_ADDRESS>:3306;dbname=<DATABASE>
```

Although the proxy hangs or crashes when attempting to connect it does report a valid connection when testing the connection from MySQL Workbench. When I attempt the actual connection, though, it either hangs after "New connection for..." message or crashes with a fatal error: unexpected signal during runtime execution after issuing the "New connection for..." message.

Comment: To clarify, you have "Require SSL" enabled on the Cloud SQL instance?

Comment: Yes, that is how it is set. I am able to connect from MySQL Workbench using the SSL certificates.